# Is "can't" the best possible and most natural option here?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

Girl: Mom says we **can't** eat with our hands when we're out.

Is "can't" the best possible and most natural option here if the mom doesn't want the girl to eat with her hands when out? Or would "allowed to" or "mustn't" be better choices?

Answer (score 2):

As a native British English speaker, "Girl: Mom says we can't eat with our hands when we're out" sounds perfectly natural.

"Can't" or "cannot" taken literally would mean that the girls were unable to eat with their hands, which is probably not the case here.

In this context, of a mother instructing her daughters, the listener would understand that the daughters could actually eat with their hands, but that there would be adverse consequences if they did. That is to say they cannot do it without consequences.

The other two suggestions sound perfectly natural and also convey the absence of permission rather than ability.

"Girl: Mom says we're not allowed to eat with our hands when we're out."

"Girl: Mom says we mustn't eat with our hands when we're out."

Comment: When I was a small kid in London, if you said to the teacher 'Can I (do something)?' (e.g. go to the toilet) she used to say 'you can, but you may not'. Very old fashioned upper- and middle-class kids might have said 'Mother says we mayn't eat with our hands while we're out' but that was 65 years ago, and nobody talks like that now. However, in my family you couldn't eat with your hands, ever, in the house or out of it, except maybe fruit, candy, etc.

Comment: American English note: all of this answer applies, **except** American English speakers would not ever say "mustn't."

Comment: @Juhasz - at random - "**We mustn't** allow some upstart state to dislodge New York from its pinnacle as tone-setter for the nation, especially in matters as critical to the morale of Americans as the ethical code for their lawyers." -  Sydney Schanberg, 
_New York Times, Feb. 12, 1983.

Comment: @Juhasz - another: Liz Smith, born in Fort Worth, Texas, in 1923. In the 1960s, she was entertainment editor for Cosmopolitan and SportsIllustrated. Her 2000 memoir, Natural Blonde, was a New York Times best seller. “**We mustn’t** take ourselves too seriously in this world of gossip,” she told the Associated Press in 1987.